# Doctrine refresh occurring without refresh added to cascade options

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, entity, cascade

I'm having a problem with doctrine refresh, refreshing associations even if refresh is not in the cascade options.  Below is part of a ymal mapping for an ItemNode entity.

```
oneToOne:
orderItem:
  targetEntity: OS\Domain\Entity\Order\OrderItem
  mappedBy: itemNode
zoneHistory:
  targetEntity: OS\Domain\Entity\Zone\ZoneHistory
  mappedBy: itemNode
  cascade: ['persist']
```

A refresh on an ItemNode object will refresh its data, however, data on its zoneHistory is also being refreshed.  For example, ZoneHistory has a status field that was changed earlier, but after the refresh, the status is reverted.

The interesting part, is that any change on the OrderItem is not refreshed unless refresh is added to the cascade.

```
oneToOne:
orderItem:
  targetEntity: OS\Domain\Entity\Order\OrderItem
  mappedBy: itemNode
  cascade: ['refresh']
```

The behavior of the OrderItem is what I would expect, but the ZoneHistory is being refreshed regardless.  I'm at a loss as to what is going on.

Thanks for any suggestions.